# DevilsPie2 Not Working With Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome-Desktop

Tags: gnome, xorg, lua, devilspie, gdevilspie

Ok.. I finally got around to installing devilspie2 and running through [this very clear tutorial](https://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2017/205/Tutorial-Devilspie2).  Of course, it is not working.  However, all my reading leads to 3 year old articles and troubleshooting.

Question 1:

Is devilspie2 still applicable / compatible with gnome version 3.36.8 on ubuntu 20.04 running X11 window manager?

Assuming it is still applicable / compatible... (github repository still active https://github.com/dsalt/devilspie2)

Question 2:

What am I doing wrong?  My script(s) have no effect on windows of any applications:

```
debug_print("Application: " .. get_application_name())
debug_print("Window: " .. get_window_name());

if (get_window_name() == "gedit") then
    set_window_workspace(8);
end

if (get_window_name() == "Mozilla Firefox") then
  set_window_geometry(50, 100, 800, 600);
end
```

`devilspie2 --debug` runs without problem and confirms that is reading the file that contains my scripts

```
Using scripts from folder: /home/user/.config/devilspie2
------------
List of Lua files handling "window_open" events in folder:
/home/user/.config/devilspie2/debug.lua
List of Lua files handling "window_close" events in folder:
List of Lua files handling "window_focus" events in folder:
List of Lua files handling "window_blur" events in folder:
------------
```

I can find no errors in my system logs related to devilspie2 and/or lua

I have restarted display-manager and I have fully rebooted... no effect.

Any tips?

**Additional Info**
This my list of installed gnome-extensions in case there is some sort of conflict someone can recognize:
[image]

Comment: I am using it for many years, now in Ubuntu 22.04, so it definitely should work (on Xorg). I cannot see what you may have wrong, though. It has to be running in order to work.

Comment: @vanadium  so how can I verify that it is running? is there a systemd daemon?

Comment: the debug detects window open/close but there is no effect on windows by the scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1:
> Is devilspie2 still applicable / compatible with gnome version 3.36.8 on > ubuntu 20.04 running X11 window manager?

It is, even on 22.04, provided your run X11. It will not work on Wayland.

> Question 2:
> What am I doing wrong? My script(s) have no effect on windows of any applications:

If your configuration file is correct, and `devilspie2` is running (check in the output of `ps ax | grep devilspie2`) then the installation should be correct. There still may be specific reasons why some rules do not work.

- `get_window_name()` will return the window title. `(get_window_name() == "Mozilla Firefox")` will only match a window with the exact title "Mozilla Firefox", i.e., an empty, new Firefox window. A window of Gedit never is named `gedit`, so will never be matched. Use e.g. `(string.match(get_window_name(), "Mozilla Firefox"))` or `(string.match(get_window_name(), "gedit"))` to match a substring in the window title.
- `set_window_workspace(8);` will work only provided there is a workspace 8. For this to work on Gnome Shell, change to "Static workspaces" in "Settings", "Multitasking" (Ubuntu 22.04) or in Gnome Tweaks (earlier versions).

*Tips*

- You can "debug" your devilpie2 setup by killing the running proces (`killall devilspie2`, then adapt the configuration file, then restart devilspie2. In that terminal, you can conveniently kill devilspie2 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and restart it again.
- A quite comprehensive manual listing all commands is hidden on your system after you installed `devilspie2`. Use `less /usr/share/doc/devilspie2/README.gz` to see it.
- Do not hesitate to use the window class instead of a title. That can for example avoid that a firefox window opened on an article about gedit is being matched as a gedit window:

  ```
    if (get_window_class() == "Gedit") then
        set_window_workspace(8);
    end
  ```

  See the window class in the output of `wmctl -lx`, or `xprop | grep WM_CLASS` (second entry).

Comment: much appreciate the expended advice...I seem to have gotten devilspie2 working for all my core apps except keepass.. see the above edit to my post... any additional advice appreciated.

Comment: You should not change the scope and focus of a question. Feel free to open an dedicated question for these problems specific to your use case of KeepasX.

Comment: Fair enough... I will open a new question... thx for the advice

Comment: whoops... there's 50. thanks for the help.